# notifyDataSetChanged Method Takes Away Smooth Scrolling From Tabs

Tags: android, material-design

I am currently using Material Design in an Android app that I am making. In this app, I am using the Material Design tab layout to display some information that I am receiving. However when I tap the tabs, the animation is not smooth, and it is very abrupt. Sliding to go to the other tab, however is very smooth.

```
    mTabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.chem_tab_layout);
    mGenericAdapter = new GenericPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
    mPager.setAdapter(mGenericAdapter);

    //Notice how the Tab Layout links with the Pager Adapter
    mTabLayout.setTabsFromPagerAdapter(mGenericAdapter);

    //Notice how The Tab Layout and View Pager object are linked
    mTabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mPager);
    mPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(mTabLayout){

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            mGenericAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

    });
```

That is my code for setting the adapter, etc.

This is my custom adapter code for the tabs:

```
class GenericPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

public GenericPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    ChemGridActivity.MyFragment myFragment = new ChemGridActivity.MyFragment();
    return myFragment;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return 3; //returns number of tabs that need to be created
}

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {

    if (position == 0) return "Chemistry";
    if (position == 1) return "Mathematics";
    if (position == 2) return "Physics";

    else return null;
}

@Override    
public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
    return POSITION_NONE;
}
```

I feel that the choppy transition between tabs is caused by the overriden method `onPageSelected` method when I add `onPageChangeListener`. What do I add to this method to make tapping on tabs a smoother animation?

Comment: Sorry I still haven't found a solution to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing much about the internals of your classes, I imagine the problem is not that you have a listener, but *what* you are doing inside that listener.

In the case of most adapters `notifyDataSetChanged()` will cause it to re-render the entire view again (including all pages).

Seeing as you haven't specified what the intent here with the notification is, it's hard to tell you how you can do this in an alternative way, but you do need to do something less intensive if you want the animation to remain smooth.

I suspect you just want to change which fragment is shown, in which case just use the FragmentManager where necessary, remembering to reuse fragments which have already been seen once.

**EDIT** Based on additional info in comments

```
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    //POSITION_SOMETHINHG would be one of a set of constants to indicate hwa to display
    return ChemGridActivity.MyFragment.newInstance(ChemGridActivity.MyFragment.POSITION_SOMETHINHG);
}

public class ChemGridActivity.MyFragment ... {

    private static final String KEY_DISPLAY_TYPE = "KEY_DISPLAY_TYPE";

    public static final int POSITION_SOMETHINHG = 11111;

    public static MyFragment newInstance(int display) {
        MyFragment f = new MyFragment();
        Bundle bund = new Bundle();
        bund.putInt(KEY_DISPLAY_TYPE, display);
        f.setArguments(bund);
        return f;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Bundle args = getArguments();
        if (args != null) {
            mDisplay = args.getInt(KEY_DISPLAY_TYPE, 0);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater, final ViewGroup container, final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_layout, container, false);
        //TODO: change something based on mDisplay 
        return view;
    }
```

Comment: Well, the sliding animation works just fine. The reason I have to implement `notifyDataSetChanged()` is because for some reason the images that I am displaying in each tab are not being refreshed. Calling the `notifyDataSetChanged()` method allows me to refresh the whole view to display the correct images. Is there another way to add the smooth animation on page selected?

Comment: You need to post your getView method and your layout. (And If it's that you only want to show an image for each page you don't need all the overhead of separate fragments)

Comment: I only have  one fragment and I'm inflating it based on the tab selected.

Comment: so then you should have a .setImage(...) method on your fragment rather than recreate the whole view and children. I'll edit my answer with an example

Comment: I am also using a GridView. So, in the GridView I inflate an array of images onto the screen depending on the tab selected, so I can't use `setImage()`.

Comment: It doesn't really matter what you're doing in the fragment (although all the hard coding is bad). But what you need to make the fragment display correctly not rerender the entire view and all it's children, because that's what's taking time. If that doesn't mean calling setImage fine, but you need a way to signify to the fragment you get from getItem, what it should show

Comment: So if I update using the code you added, then I don't have to override the `onPageSelected()` method  and add the `notifyDataSetChanged()` method?

Comment: Also, the `addExtra()` method in your code is not a method for the Bundle class.

Comment: just change it to putExtra

Comment: `putExtra()` is not a method for Bundle, but a method for Intent.

Comment: If you know what you're looking for because of this then why are you complaining like you are owed something?

Comment: I'm not complaining, I'm just looking for an answer...I can't find a method in the Bundle class that resembles putInt().

Comment: Do you use an IDE like Android Studio or are you looking at docs (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html)? In Studio you should be able to just start typing and press ctrl+space to see available methods that match. Put int is definitely there (and you can then press ctrl+q to see more into on that method if needed)

Comment: Weird, I didn't see that method in the developer guides.

Comment: Hi, I'm not sure what you are doing with mDisplay. Can you please explain?

Comment: As i think the todo in the code explains - keeping a reference to what you're displaying so you can check it and do different logic based on the value in onCreateView